# New finder not generating the implementation (M3)

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

I have a working project on Spring Roo 2 M3. I realized that i needed a new finder apart from the ones that i created when i was bootstraping the project.
I generated the finder in the roo console:

```
finder add --entity ~.domain.Usuario --name findByUsername
```

It created the right annotation in the java repository

```
@RooFinder("findByUsername")
```

and the method in the repository aspect

```
public abstract Page<Usuario> UsuarioRepository.findByUsername(String username, Pageable pageable);
```

but it didn't generate that finder in the service neither the service implementation like the other finders that i previously generated.

I googled it for some days and tried to fix it my self but i made no progress.

---

*note: this already happened to me on other spring roo 2 M3 project some months ago. I had the same problem for like a week and then after many random tampering with the code finally the roo console triggered the changes but i couldn't figured out why it worked.*

---

**EDIT:** log.roo

```
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 18:32:01
project setup --topLevelPackage ar.edu.um.ingsoftware --projectName "umbook"
jpa setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE --hostName 127.0.0.1 --databaseName umbook --userName root
entity jpa --class ~.reference.Persona --abstract
field string --fieldName username --notNull 
field string --fieldName password --notNull
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Usuario  --extends ~.reference.Persona
field string --fieldName email --notNull
field string --fieldName nombre --notNull 
field string --fieldName apellido --notNull
field date --fieldName fechaNacimiento --type java.util.Calendar --past
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Administrador  --extends ~.reference.Persona
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Comentario
field string --fieldName contenido --notNull
field reference --fieldName autor --type ~.domain.Usuario
field date --fieldName timestmp --type java.util.Calendar
repository jpa --all
finder add --name findByEmailEquals --entity ~.domain.Usuario
finder add --name findByNombreLike --entity ~.domain.Usuario
finder add --name findByApellidoLike --entity ~.domain.Usuario
service --all
web mvc setup
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
// script --file script_roo
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 18:32:26
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 18:57:39
web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF --pathPrefix 'find'
web mvc language --code es --useAsDefault 
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF 
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 19:23:08
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 19:23:31
focus --class ~.domain.Usuario
field list --fieldName comentarios --type ~.domain.Comentario --mappedBy listaDeComentarios --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY 
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 19:41:26
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 19:41:37
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 19:42:18
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 19:42:36
focus --class ~.domain.Comentario 
focus --class ~.domain.Usuario
// [failed] field list --fieldName comentariosHechos --type ~.domain.Comentario --mappedBy autor  --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY 
// [failed] field list --fieldName comentarios --type ~.domain.Comentario
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 19:53:59
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 19:54:16
focus --class ~.domain.Usuario
field list --fieldName comentarios --type ~.domain.Comentario
focus --class ~.domain.Comentario
focus --class ~.domain.Usuario
field list --fieldName comentarios --type ~.domain.Comentario --cardinality MANY_TO_MANY 
field list --fieldName comentarios --type ~.domain.Comentario
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 19:58:35
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-06 19:58:50
// [failed] field list --fieldName comentariosHechos --type ~.domain.Comentario --mappedBy autor
focus --class ~.domain.Usuario
field list --fieldName comentariosHechos --type ~.domain.Comentario --mappedBy autor
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-06 23:36:33
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-16 18:03:39
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-19 04:51:01
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-24 20:40:34
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-24 20:42:02
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-24 20:42:15
help
project scan now
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-25 00:49:54
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-25 00:50:07
project scan status
project scan now
finder add --entity ~.domain.Usuario --name findByUsername
project scan now
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-26 04:59:57
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-26 05:00:09
project scan now
project scan now
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-26 05:12:02
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-26 05:12:13
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-26 05:15:11
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-26 05:16:30
project scan status
project scan status
project scan now
help
metadata status
help
version
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-26 05:36:24
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-02-26 19:59:43
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-02-26 20:59:20
```

---

EDIT2: Added UsuarioRepository.java after the push-in

```
package ar.edu.um.ingsoftware.repository;
import ar.edu.um.ingsoftware.domain.Usuario;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.jpa.annotations.RooJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.jpa.annotations.RooFinder;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
/**
 * = UsuarioRepository
 *
 * TODO Auto-generated class documentation
 *
 */
@RooJpaRepository(entity = Usuario.class, finders = { @RooFinder("findByEmailEquals"), @RooFinder("findByNombreLike"), @RooFinder("findByApellidoLike"), @RooFinder("findByUsername") })
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long>, UsuarioRepositoryCustom {

    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param email
     * @param pageable
     * @return Page
     */
    public abstract Page<Usuario> findByEmailEquals(String email, Pageable pageable);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param email
     * @return Long
     */
    public abstract long countByEmailEquals(String email);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param nombre
     * @param pageable
     * @return Page
     */
    public abstract Page<Usuario> findByNombreLike(String nombre, Pageable pageable);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param nombre
     * @return Long
     */
    public abstract long countByNombreLike(String nombre);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param apellido
     * @param pageable
     * @return Page
     */
    public abstract Page<Usuario> findByApellidoLike(String apellido, Pageable pageable);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param apellido
     * @return Long
     */
    public abstract long countByApellidoLike(String apellido);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param pageable
     * @return Page
     */
    public abstract Page<Usuario> findByUsername(String username, Pageable pageable);


    /**
     * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return Long
     */
    public abstract long countByUsername(String username);

}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a sample "log.roo" filw to try to reproduce your issue?  Regards,

Comment: well i dont know the exactly the conditions to reproduce this bug. The only similarity between the two projects where i suffered this bug were that in both i tried to add new finders after significant time of the initial bootstraping of the project. I can post the full log.roo of this project if you want.

Comment: Would be great if you could post it to have more info to reproduce the issue. Anyway... did you try closing and reopening the Spring Roo shell to check if the new method is generated? Regards

Comment: Yeah, i re-opened the roo shell multiple times. Also tried restarting the IDE (STS) and even editing some parts of the monitored files trying to trigger the roo shell changes. I'm adding the log.roo in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyze your issue, seems like some problem with the Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 metadata listeners affects to the service generation when a new finder is included.

This problem has been fixed in Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 and it will be published really soon.

Anyway, if you make `push-in` of the `findByUsername` method, the service interface and the service implementation must include it.

Let me know if you have any problem with that!

Hope it helps,

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Well i tried pushing-in the finder methods but it didn't triggered any change on the shell. I also tried pushing-in the whole user repository aspect but it didn't make any difference. (I added the result of the push-in on the post)

Comment: Don't worry. I was checking your issue with the ROO 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (current development version that will be the RC1 version) and it has been fixed! Regards,

Answer (score 0):

the problem has not been fixed, try to add a new finder, equal I generated the finder in the roo console, but if I generate the new project using a script where I add the lines, it generates the same classes and repositories that are generated when doing so with a console, but without errors in the repositoryImpl.

case A (use console):

```js
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RELEASE [rev 4a2e9f1] log opened at 2019-05-13 18:06:10
project setup --topLevelPackage testfinder2 --projectName "testfinder2" --java 8 --packaging WAR
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RELEASE [rev 4a2e9f1] log closed at 2019-05-13 18:06:11
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.RELEASE [rev 4a2e9f1] log opened at 2019-05-13 18:06:13
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --hostName --databaseName prueba --userName root --password 
!g obr:deploy org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java
!g obr:start org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java
addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName  org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCompanias --plural Companias --schema blade --table gl_companias --identifierColumn id_compania --entityFormatExpression "#{cveCompania}"
field string --fieldName cveCompania --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column cve_compania
field string --fieldName razonSocial --sizeMax 80 --notNull --column razon_social
field string --fieldName domicilio --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column domicilio
field string --fieldName rfc --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column rfc
field string --fieldName codigoPostal --sizeMax 6 --notNull --column codigo_postal
field string --fieldName telefonos --sizeMax 70 --notNull --column telefonos
field string --fieldName fax --sizeMax 25 --notNull --column fax
field string --fieldName email --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email
field string --fieldName contacto --sizeMax 40 --notNull --column contacto
field date --fieldName fechaIngresoSistema --type java.util.Date --column fecha_ingreso_sistema
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column comentarios
field number --fieldName paisDefault --type java.lang.Long --column pais_default
field string --fieldName pagina --sizeMax 25 --notNull --column pagina
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --plural CatsClientes --schema blade --table vnt_cat_clientes --identifierColumn id_cliente --entityFormatExpression "#{nombre}#{rfc}"
field string --fieldName cveCliente --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column cve_cliente
field string --fieldName nombre --sizeMax 70 --notNull --column nombre
field string --fieldName razonSocial --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column razon_social
field string --fieldName rfc --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column rfc
field string --fieldName tipoContribuyente --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column tipo_contribuyente
field string --fieldName calleDomicilio --sizeMax 120 --notNull --column calle_domicilio
field string --fieldName telefonoComercial --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_comercial
field string --fieldName telefonoPagos --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_pagos
field string --fieldName telefonoBodega --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_bodega
field string --fieldName telefonoVentas --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_ventas
field string --fieldName emailComercial --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_comercial
field string --fieldName emailPagos --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_pagos
field string --fieldName emailVentas --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_ventas
field string --fieldName emailBodega --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_bodega
field string --fieldName domicilioBodega --sizeMax 120 --notNull --column domicilio_bodega
field string --fieldName representanteLegal --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column representante_legal
field string --fieldName atencionVentas --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column atencion_ventas
field string --fieldName atencionPagos --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column atencion_pagos
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column 
field boolean --fieldName estatus  --column estatus 
field number --fieldName idColoniaFiscal --type int --column id_colonia_fiscal
field number --fieldName idColoniaEntregas --type int --column id_colonia_entregas
field date --fieldName ultimaActualizacion --type java.util.Date --column ultima_actualizacion
field string --fieldName cveUsuarioActualizacion --sizeMax 10 --notNull --column cve_usuario_actualizacion
field string --fieldName localizacion --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column localizacion
field boolean --fieldName moroso  --column moroso  
field date --fieldName fechaRegisto --type java.util.Date --column fecha_registro
field boolean --fieldName esProspecto  --column es_prospecto 
field date --fieldName fechaUltimoMovimiento --type java.util.Date --column fecha_ultimo_movimiento
field number --fieldName idUsoCfdi --type int --column id_uso_cfdi
field string --fieldName metodoPago --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column metodo_pago
field string --fieldName formaPago --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column forma_pago
field string --fieldName latitude --sizeMax 20 --notNull --column latitude
field string --fieldName longitude --sizeMax 20 --notNull --column longitude
field string --fieldName verificado --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column verificado
field string --fieldName imgIfe --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column img_ife
field string --fieldName imgComprobante --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column img_comprobante
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --plural CatsColonias --schema blade --table gl_cat_colonias_n --identifierColumn id_colonia --entityFormatExpression "#{nombreColonia}"
field number --fieldName idMunicipio --type int --column id_municipio 
field string --fieldName nombreColonia --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column nombre_colonia
field string --fieldName cp --sizeMax 45 --notNull --column cp
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --plural CatsClientesParametros --schema blade --table vnt_cat_clientes_parametros --identifierColumn id_clientesparametros --entityFormatExpression "#{cveCliente}"
field string --fieldName cveCompania --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column cve_compania
field string --fieldName cveCliente --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column cve_cliente
field string --fieldName cveCentroCosto --sizeMax 30 --notNull --column cve_centro_costo
field string --fieldName tipoCliente --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column tipo_cliente
field string --fieldName giroCliente --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column giro_cliente
field number --fieldName numContrato --type java.lang.Long --column num_contrato 
field string --fieldName calificaComprador --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column califica_comprador
field string --fieldName calificaPagador --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column califica_pagador
field boolean --fieldName esProspecto --column es_prospecto
field number --fieldName diasVencimientoCartera --type int --column dias_vencimiento_cartera
field number --fieldName limiteCredito --type java.math.BigDecimal --column limite_credito
field number --fieldName minimoCompra --type java.math.BigDecimal --column minimo_compra
field number --fieldName pctDescuentoEspecial --type java.math.BigDecimal --column pct_descuento_especial 
field string --fieldName estatus --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column estatus
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column comentarios
field boolean --fieldName identificacionOficial --column identificacion_oficial 
field boolean --fieldName comprobanteDomicilio --column comprobante_domicilio 
field boolean --fieldName altaHacienda --column alta_hacienda
field boolean --fieldName actaConstitutiva --column acta_constitutiva
field boolean --fieldName rfc --column rfc
field boolean --fieldName contratoConfirmado --column contrato_confirmado 
field string --fieldName familia --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column familia
field number --fieldName idTipoCliente --type int --column id_tipo_cliente  
field number --fieldName idCrediticio --type int --column id_crediticio
field number --fieldName idImportancia --type int --column id_importancia
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --plural CatsPerfilesCLientesProductos --schema blade --table vnt_cat_perfil_cliente_productos --identifierColumn id_perfilclienteproductos --entityFormatExpression "#{familia}"
field string --fieldName familia --sizeMax 4 --notNull --column familia
field string --fieldName nombreTipoFamilia --sizeMax 55 --notNull --column nombre_tipo_familia
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN
field set --fieldName CatsColoniasN --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --joinColumnName id_colonia --fetch EAGER
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCompanias
field set --fieldName CompaniasClientesParametros --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_compania --fetch EAGER
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes
field set --fieldName ClientesClientesParametros --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_cliente --fetch EAGER
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos
field set --fieldName ClientesPerfilProductos --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_perfilclienteproductos --fetch EAGER
repository jpa --all
service --all
dto --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesBuscador
field string --fieldName nombre
field string --fieldName rfc
dto --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasNBuscador
field string --fieldName nombreColonia
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --name findByNombreAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesBuscador
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --name findByNombreColoniaAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasNBuscador
web mvc setup
web mvc language --code es --useAsDefault 
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all 
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --responseType THYMELEAF
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --name findByFamiliaAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductosBuscador
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --responseType THYMELEAF
```

case b (use this script):

```js
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --hostName xxx --databaseName prueba --userName root --password 

addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName  org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java

//GlCompanias
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCompanias --plural Companias --schema blade --table gl_companias --identifierColumn id_compania --entityFormatExpression "#{cveCompania}"
field string --fieldName cveCompania --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column cve_compania
field string --fieldName razonSocial --sizeMax 80 --notNull --column razon_social
field string --fieldName domicilio --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column domicilio
field string --fieldName rfc --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column rfc
field string --fieldName codigoPostal --sizeMax 6 --notNull --column codigo_postal
field string --fieldName telefonos --sizeMax 70 --notNull --column telefonos
field string --fieldName fax --sizeMax 25 --notNull --column fax
field string --fieldName email --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email
field string --fieldName contacto --sizeMax 40 --notNull --column contacto
field date --fieldName fechaIngresoSistema --type java.util.Date --column fecha_ingreso_sistema
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column comentarios
field number --fieldName paisDefault --type java.lang.Long --column pais_default
field string --fieldName pagina --sizeMax 25 --notNull --column pagina

//VntCatClientes
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --plural CatsClientes --schema blade --table vnt_cat_clientes --identifierColumn id_cliente --entityFormatExpression "#{nombre}#{rfc}"
field string --fieldName cveCliente --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column cve_cliente
field string --fieldName nombre --sizeMax 70 --notNull --column nombre
field string --fieldName razonSocial --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column razon_social
field string --fieldName rfc --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column rfc
field string --fieldName tipoContribuyente --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column tipo_contribuyente
field string --fieldName calleDomicilio --sizeMax 120 --notNull --column calle_domicilio
field string --fieldName telefonoComercial --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_comercial
field string --fieldName telefonoPagos --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_pagos
field string --fieldName telefonoBodega --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_bodega
field string --fieldName telefonoVentas --sizeMax 60 --notNull --column telefono_ventas
field string --fieldName emailComercial --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_comercial
field string --fieldName emailPagos --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_pagos
field string --fieldName emailVentas --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_ventas
field string --fieldName emailBodega --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column email_bodega
field string --fieldName domicilioBodega --sizeMax 120 --notNull --column domicilio_bodega
field string --fieldName representanteLegal --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column representante_legal
field string --fieldName atencionVentas --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column atencion_ventas
field string --fieldName atencionPagos --sizeMax 35 --notNull --column atencion_pagos
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column 
field boolean --fieldName estatus  --column estatus 
field number --fieldName idColoniaFiscal --type int --column id_colonia_fiscal
field number --fieldName idColoniaEntregas --type int --column id_colonia_entregas
field date --fieldName ultimaActualizacion --type java.util.Date --column ultima_actualizacion
field string --fieldName cveUsuarioActualizacion --sizeMax 10 --notNull --column cve_usuario_actualizacion
field string --fieldName localizacion --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column localizacion
field boolean --fieldName moroso  --column moroso  
field date --fieldName fechaRegisto --type java.util.Date --column fecha_registro
field boolean --fieldName esProspecto  --column es_prospecto 
field date --fieldName fechaUltimoMovimiento --type java.util.Date --column fecha_ultimo_movimiento
field number --fieldName idUsoCfdi --type int --column id_uso_cfdi
field string --fieldName metodoPago --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column metodo_pago
field string --fieldName formaPago --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column forma_pago
field string --fieldName latitude --sizeMax 20 --notNull --column latitude
field string --fieldName longitude --sizeMax 20 --notNull --column longitude
field string --fieldName verificado --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column verificado
field string --fieldName imgIfe --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column img_ife
field string --fieldName imgComprobante --sizeMax 200 --notNull --column img_comprobante

//GlCatColoniasN
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --plural CatsColonias --schema blade --table gl_cat_colonias_n --identifierColumn id_colonia --entityFormatExpression "#{nombreColonia}"
field number --fieldName idMunicipio --type int --column id_municipio 
field string --fieldName nombreColonia --sizeMax 100 --notNull --column nombre_colonia
field string --fieldName cp --sizeMax 45 --notNull --column cp

//VntCatClientesParametros
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --plural CatsClientesParametros --schema blade --table vnt_cat_clientes_parametros --identifierColumn id_clientesparametros --entityFormatExpression "#{cveCliente}"
field string --fieldName cveCompania --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column cve_compania
field string --fieldName cveCliente --sizeMax 15 --notNull --column cve_cliente
field string --fieldName cveCentroCosto --sizeMax 30 --notNull --column cve_centro_costo
field string --fieldName tipoCliente --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column tipo_cliente
field string --fieldName giroCliente --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column giro_cliente
field number --fieldName numContrato --type java.lang.Long --column num_contrato 
field string --fieldName calificaComprador --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column califica_comprador
field string --fieldName calificaPagador --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column califica_pagador
field boolean --fieldName esProspecto --column es_prospecto
field number --fieldName diasVencimientoCartera --type int --column dias_vencimiento_cartera
field number --fieldName limiteCredito --type java.math.BigDecimal --column limite_credito
field number --fieldName minimoCompra --type java.math.BigDecimal --column minimo_compra
field number --fieldName pctDescuentoEspecial --type java.math.BigDecimal --column pct_descuento_especial 
field string --fieldName estatus --sizeMax 1 --notNull --column estatus
field string --fieldName comentarios --sizeMax 255 --notNull --column comentarios
field boolean --fieldName identificacionOficial --column identificacion_oficial 
field boolean --fieldName comprobanteDomicilio --column comprobante_domicilio 
field boolean --fieldName altaHacienda --column alta_hacienda
field boolean --fieldName actaConstitutiva --column acta_constitutiva
field boolean --fieldName rfc --column rfc
field boolean --fieldName contratoConfirmado --column contrato_confirmado 
field string --fieldName familia --sizeMax 3 --notNull --column familia
field number --fieldName idTipoCliente --type int --column id_tipo_cliente  
field number --fieldName idCrediticio --type int --column id_crediticio
field number --fieldName idImportancia --type int --column id_importancia

//VntCatPerfilClienteProductos
entity jpa --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --plural CatsPerfilesCLientesProductos --schema blade --table vnt_cat_perfil_cliente_productos --identifierColumn id_perfilclienteproductos --entityFormatExpression "#{familia}"
field string --fieldName familia --sizeMax 4 --notNull --column familia
field string --fieldName nombreTipoFamilia --sizeMax 55 --notNull --column nombre_tipo_familia

//VntCatClientes
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN
field set --fieldName CatsColoniasN --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --joinColumnName id_colonia --fetch EAGER

//VntCatClientesParametros
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCompanias
field set --fieldName CompaniasClientesParametros --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_compania --fetch EAGER
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes
field set --fieldName ClientesClientesParametros --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_cliente --fetch EAGER
focus --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos
field set --fieldName ClientesPerfilProductos --type ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesParametros --joinColumnName id_perfilclienteproductos --fetch EAGER


repository jpa --all
service --all


//DTOs

dto --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesBuscador
field string --fieldName nombre
field string --fieldName rfc

dto --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasNBuscador
field string --fieldName nombreColonia


//test
dto --class ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductosBuscador
field string --fieldName familia



//FINDERs
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --name findByNombreAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientesBuscador
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --name findByNombreColoniaAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasNBuscador

// test
finder add --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --name findByFamiliaAllIgnoreCase --formBean ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductosBuscador




web mvc setup
web mvc language --code es --useAsDefault 
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all 

// DECLARA PARA LA PARTE WEB EL FINDER PARA UBICARLO EN EL CRUD: OJO VER EL URL AL MOMENTO DE HAPLICAR EL FILTRO
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatClientes --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.GlCatColoniasN --responseType THYMELEAF


//test
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos
web mvc finder --entity ~.springbootbackendbiochem.model.entity.VntCatPerfilClienteProductos --responseType THYMELEAF
```